# Delete request causes node server to freeze

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

So I have a mini express app where users can register, login and delete their account. Due html not supporting DELETE I used the npm package methodOverride.

This is what my form and express-override middleware looks like:

***server.js***

```
// Method override
app.use(
  methodOverride(function (req, res) {
    if (req.body && typeof req.body === 'object' && '_method' in req.body) {
      let method = req.body._method;
      delete req.body._method;
      return method;
    }
  })
```

***index.hbs***

```
    <form action="/profile/delete/{{_id}}" method="POST" class="pt-2">
     <label for="delete-input_confirmation"></label>
     <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
     <button type="submit" class="btn delete-confirm">Confirm</button>
    </form>
```

Now in my users.js for the delete request:

```
    router.delete('/profile/delete/:id', ensureAuth, async (req, res) => {
      try {
        let userId = await LocalUser.findById(req.params.id);
    
        if (!userId) {
          return res.render('/');
        } else {
          await LocalUser.findOneAndRemove({ _id: req.params.id });
          res.redirect('/register');
          console.log(userId);
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return res.render('/');
      }
    });
```

Now what happens with the the code above it goes through fine but it doesn't move past the DELETE request and render the /register page. Then the node server just stops working and I have to restart it and clear my cache. In my mongo db it removes the user so I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: Not probably the problem you are asking about, but why are you doing `res.render('/');`.  Shouldn't you be passing a filename to `res.render()`?

Comment: I fixed what you said but it still didn't solve the problem. I just tested it and when I remove  async await and the try catch, everything goes through normally but the user doesn't get deleted from the db

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using `.findOneAndRemove()`?  According to the doc, you should be using `.findOneAndDelete()` unless you have a specific reason not to.

Comment: I don't know MongoDb particularly well, but all the examples I find show something like this: `LocalUser.findOneAndDelete({ _id: ObjectId(req.params.id) });` or just `LocalUser.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id)`.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks for your response. I tried re writing the delete request using findoneanddelete and it worked. However when I try to include async and try/catch it messes the express server and I have to clear site cache.

Comment: Please be more specific.  What does "messes the express server" mean?  What exactly happens?  Are you seeing any errors in the server console?  If so, what is the EXACT error message?

Comment: Sorry for not being specific. When I delete the account in my console I see the DELETE request with a response of 304. Then after that nothing happens, it just sits there and if I try to reload the page it just wont load until I go to the application storage and delete site storage. Just to note it actually does delete the user in the mongodb. When I don't use async everything works perfectly fine.

Comment: Application site storage?  What kind of client app is this?   This sounds like something happening in the client, not the server.

Comment: in the dev tools you can go to application tab and clear site storage. Its an express app with handlebars template engine. Idk why but clearing the site storage works.

Comment: Do you have a server-side session object tied to that user and when you delete the user object that session gets wedged or you also need to remove the session when you remove the current user.  If so, there is probably some missing error handling elsewhere in your session logic.  Clearing site storage would be removing the session cookie for you, forcing a new empty session to be established.  If this sounds like a possibility, show us your server-side session code.

Comment: Thank you so much. You were right about the session, it was persisting even after the user got deleted so I put `req.session.destroy()` and it worked!! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll put my comments into an answer since this ended up solving it for you.

If you're deleting the current user, but leaving their server-side session open, then that can lead to session issues.  To clear that session, you can either call `req.session.destroy()` or you can remove the session cookie (and the session will become detached from that browser and eventually age away).

The fact that your site becomes non-functional when you have a session of a removed user probably means that you have some error handling problems in your session logic or in accessing the database on behalf of a non-existent user.  Your code should be able to field errors when this happens and at least report an error, but probably force the user back to `/login`.